# Exp a -> a in Haskell Accelerate

Tags: haskell, accelerate-haskell

Is there a function with such type signature: `Exp a -> a` in accelerate library for Haskell?

For example, I have an expression:

```
max = maximum mat !! 0
```

where
`mat :: Acc (Matrix Int)`

Then, max has type `Exp Int`, but I'd like max to be expressed a simple haskell's `Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to convert the `Exp` into an `Acc`, then run that, and finally index the resulting array:

```hs
indexArray (run (unit max)) Z
```

Perhaps it is easier then to use the maximum array directly:

```hs
indexArray (run (maximum mat)) (0 :. Z)
```